# How to get job run result logs of notebook in databricks using Python or Pyspark or scala

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I have to get the job run results logs of notebook in databricks using python or pyspark or scala and write those log details to a file. I'm not able to get these logs.Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

when you create your cluster in databricks, there is a tab where you can specify the log directory (empty by default).

Logs are written on DBFS, so you just have to specify the directory you want.

[clusters/log-delivery](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/clusters/log-delivery.html#id1)

Comment: Thanks Steven for your reply.How to get logs for only one particular job run id log?
If i create the destination path in dbfs for every 5 minutes it will log into that path but if i need only specific to that job run id then how to to get  that.Thanks in advance

Comment: @pythonUser you should probably open another question because i have no idea on that particular point